# Proguard: JobIntentService IllegalArgumentException on enabling obfuscation

Tags: android, obfuscation, android-proguard

When I enable Proguard for one of my Android library package, it results in runtime error in JobIntentService code. Services in my package extend JobIntentService and fails during enqueue time as it is obfuscated to a different name. Following is the error where r is the service

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No such service ComponentInfo{com.example.package/com.example.foo.r}
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2008)
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1950)
    at android.app.job.IJobScheduler$Stub$Proxy.enqueue(IJobScheduler.java:211)
    at android.app.JobSchedulerImpl.enqueue(JobSchedulerImpl.java:53)
```

Why is this exception thrown? Is there a generic way to retain classnames extending JobIntentService?

Tried -keepnames class * extends JobIntentService but is not working

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the full path of the JobIntentService, proguard files don't support imports:
`-keepnames class * extends android.support.v4.app.JobIntentService`

The exception appears to be thrown because the class is obfuscated.

Comment: Thanks, this worked. Could you also explain why the exception is thrown?

Comment: Just updated it. Why the down vote if it's correct and solved the problem you were having?

Comment: But, how does the class loading work if it is obfuscated?The downvote is not from me.

Comment: I'd have to look into this further, but my first guess is that the obfuscated class path doesn't match what you've declared in the manifest. Could you mark the answer as correct though?

Answer (score 0):

You have to keep all the classes, which are being referenced in the `Manifest.xml`, for example:

```
-keep public class * extends android.app.Service
```

... else it might complain `no such service`, while pointing to package `R`.

This also keeps instances of `JobIntentService`, which isn't the actual problem here (which is that the class-name of some `Service` instance referenced in the `Manifest.xml` had been obfuscated). The point is, that `JobIntentService extends Service` and any `Service` needs to be listed in the `Manifest.xml` and therefore using general rules make more senses than using a specific rule.